# In laravel middleware the parameter request id is missing

Tags: php, laravel, middleware, laravel-5.8

I have a Laravel controller with destroying method and middleware with name CheckRole.

```
public function destroy(Request $request, $id)
{
    // code to delete item
}
```

I am unable to use the $id in middleware CheckRole.

```
class CheckRole
{
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {

  }
}
```

And

```
$request->id and
$request->route('id')
```

are also not working with the middleware.
How to fix this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you need $id in the middleware? Is there any reason why you can't put the $id in to the $request?

Comment: I need $id to validate the user against role and to find items that should be in non delete category

Comment: You can get the user in the middleware using `$request->user()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$id` in the destroy function is the `id` of the resource you want to delete, so that will never be the authenticated user id a better option for checking the role might be an [authorization policy](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authorization#writing-policies) instead of a middleware.

Or get the authenticated user id by using: `auth()->id()` or `$request->user()->id`

You can also add a method in your `User` model, and check like that for example:

```
class User ...

public function isAdmin()
{
    return $this->role === 'admin';
}
```

In the middleware

```
$request->user()->isAdmin();
```

--- EDIT

So if you use a `resource` when you defined your route for example:

```
Route::resource('user', 'UsersController');
```

Then in your middleware you can access the `id` of the user like this:

```
$request->user
```

If your route is like this:

```
Route::delete('/users/{user}', 'UsersController@destroy');
```

Then again you can get it using the named parameter `$request->user`. Make sure that whatever you use on your route in the `{}` that's the name of the parameter you use to get the `id` from.

Comment: Do you meant we are unable to use resource url parameter inside a middleware

Comment: No, I didn't meant that. You can access the parameter in the middleware. Check my edit

Answer (score 1):

Getting URL Parameters in Middleware

```
class CheckRole
{
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
    $id = $request->route()->parameter('id');
  }
}
```

Comment: You just save my night! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no real safe way to do this as the user can just change the ID within the form submitted, unless you just want users who can sign in to be an admin. If this is true I would use @nakov's suggestion.

If you want to have a full permission system with roles, etc I would suggestion: https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission

A good tutorial can be found here but please do not change anything it states with the password: https://scotch.io/tutorials/user-authorization-in-laravel-54-with-spatie-laravel-permission